# Как подсветить часть svg path?

Tags: svg

Например, есть путь прямоугольника с линиями:

```
M100 100 L100 200 200 200 200 100 Z M150 100 L150 200 Z M100 150 L200 150 Z
```

Можно ли без парсинга этого пути подсветить часть пути, на который сейчас наведена мышь?

Comment: часть пути - не понятно, участок описанный одной командой?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да. Например: `M100 150 L200 150 Z` (горизонтальная линия)

Comment: боюсь нет такой возможности, можно лишь добавить эти все сегменты сразу невидимыми и показывать, ну или если их много- уже динамически их добавлять